# How do I get the value in ng-template(Angular 6)?

Tags: angular, angular6, ng-template

```
<ngx-hm-carousel [autoplay-speed]="5000" [autoplay]="true" [infinite]="true" [align]="left" [between-delay]="2000" class="carousel c-accent">

<section ngx-hm-carousel-container class="content">
    <article class="item cursor-pointer" *ngFor="let item of data" ngx-hm-carousel-item>
        <div class="img" [style.backgroundImage]="'url('+item.url+')'">
        </div>
    </article>
</section>

<ng-template #carouselDot let-model>
    <div class="ball bg-accent" [class.visible]="model.index === model.currentIndex"></div>

    <div class="my-progress">
        {{model2.progress}} //***undefined***
    </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #carouselProgress let-model2>
    <div class="progress" [style.width]="model2.progress + '%'"></div>
</ng-template>
```

Hi guys,

I can not get the value of "model2.progress" in "#carouselProgress" from outside. What can I do for it ?

Comment: Please be more clear. You should also tel how you are activating those `ng-templates` and what is the value set to `model2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are activating `carouselDot` template from `carouselProgress`. Add another `ng-content` inside `carouselProgress` template and send the value of `model2` as shown

```
<ng-template #carouselProgress let-model2="mod">
    {{model2}} --- Template 1
    -- Activates carouselDot ng template  with model2 data
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="carouselDot; context:{model :model2}"></ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

And `carouselDot` will receive `model2` data sent by `carouselProgress`

```
<ng-template #carouselDot let-model2="model">    
    <div class="my-progress">
        {{model2}} --- Template 2
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Check [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngtemplate-again?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for full Demo